# How to set the path of a Tempfile in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a couple of files that i'd like to turn into Tempfile objects.

Is there a way to do something like: `Tempfile.new(path)`?

The reason i'm asking is that I'm trying to run an ImageMagick command that creates multiple files from a single Tempfile. Unfortunatly the newly created files do not get garbage collected...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have references to those file objects, or do you know the file names?

Comment: Ruby's Tempfile takes a custom name http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html

Comment: Sorry, is `Tempfile.new('foo')` not working? or were you asking if that was the method name, because if so, good guess.

Comment: `Tempfile.new('foo')` will create a new file. I'd like to open an existing file. I have the full path (including file name) to these files. The only thing i can think of is to dump the file into a new Tempfile. Seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of something. Instead of dumping the new file into a Tempfile, just overwrite it.

```
tempfile = Tempfile.new('foo')
tempfile.close
FileUtils.mv path, tempfile.path
tempfile.open
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question itself, regardless of the question's author specific case, the place where Ruby's `Tempfile` would place (create) its files can be changed by modifying `TMPDIR` environment variable.

Like so

```
$ TMPDIR=/dev/shm ruby script.rb
```